# RequestAnimationFrame behaviour..hows it work?

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

I have been playing around with requestAnimationframe for chrome, and wondered how it actually behaves.

When i load my canvas and draw, I get a steady 60FPS. If i scroll around using offset like a click and drag around a map, the FPS will drop (as expected)...once i stop dragging around the map, the FPS creeps back up to its steady 60fps, again as expected.

Here how ever is where I'm wondered if this is delibrate for requestAnimationframe. If i drag the map around until the FPS drop, drops below 30 for an extended period of time, once i stop dragging, it climbs back up, but this time it hits 30FPS and will not go higher. It appears as if the browser decided 30FPS is perhaps the best option.

Is this delibrately done by the browser, i been trying to find out if this is the case. Because it will go to 60fps if i dont drop below 30fps for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's something that the browsers are capable of doing.
"How it's supposed to work" isn't really something that anybody can answer, here.

The reason for that is simply that under the hood is 100% browser-specific.
But it's very safe to say that yes, the browser is capable of deciding when you should be locked into a 30Hz refresh, rather than a 60Hz refresh.

An illustration of why this is the case:

`requestAnimationFrame()` is also tied into the Page Visibility API if the vendors want (very true for Chrome).
Basically, if the page isn't visible, they can slow the `requestAnimationFrame()` updates down to a few times per second or pause them altogether.

Given that knowledge, it's entirely plausible to believe that one of two things is happening:

1. they're intentionally capping you at 30fps, because they feel your experience will be more stable there, based on averaged performance data
2. they're intentionally throttling you, but there's some bug in the system (or some less than lenient math) which is preventing you from going back up to 60, after the coast has cleared, .and if they *are* using averaged performance data, then that might be part of the issue.

Either way, it is at very least mostly-intentional, with the only unanswered question being why it sticks to 30fps.
Did you leave it alone for 20 or 30 minutes after the fact, to see if it went back up at any time, afterwards?

Comment: I left it a good 15 minutes. I don't know a decent way to analyze what might be going on for the RAF to stay that low.

Comment: Well, it's not "that low".  30Hz is the next step down from 60Hz, assuming that you're dealing with vSync. Originally, rAF calls were not synced to monitor refresh, but I think that's a solved problem.  So in the case of v-sync, your options are 60fps, 30fps, 20fps, 15fps, 12fps, 10fps...

Comment: It still doesn't explain why it stays at 30, when it can go back up to 60 after the heavy processing.  If a process made it drop to 10, the logic there would be the entire animation remains at 10fps when it could be alot smootheer after the intensive process is finished. It kinda makes RAF bad choice

Answer (score 0):

You can run Timeframe analysis from Chrome DevTools to look for maverick JS that is slowing down your animation times.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

RAF will find the best place to paint your changes not the closest one.  So, if the JS in the RAF callback is taking two frames worth of time(around 16ms per frame on your 60hz hardware), then you FPS will drop to 30.

From Paul Irish via Boris
Actually, “It’s currently capped at 1000/(16 + N) fps, where N is the number of ms it takes your callback to execute. If your callback takes 1000ms to execute, then it’s capped at under 1fps. If your callback takes 1ms to execute, you get about 60fps.” (thx, Boris)
http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/